# Error: Cannot destructure property 'package' of 'node.target' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

When I run "npm i package-name " while trying to add my own library to my React project, I get the error "Cannot destructure property 'package' of 'node.target' as it is null".

I tried running nmp i, npm add and npm install but it gave the same error

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?